# YOURLS redirection intermittent

Tags: redirect, intermittent, yourls

To start...
YOURLS: 1.7.2
hosted on a server with cPanel installed
MySQL: 5.6.37
PHP: 5.3

www.aimsoftware.com.au/yourls/

I have configured a few short URLs for testing and it seems to be a bit hit and miss about when it will redirect.  Sometimes it will, sometimes it wont.  When it won't it returns to the root: www.aimsoftware.com.au/yourls

I have checked the readme file and my .htaccess is as expected.  I tried the force non-www and new apace version suggestions on this page, https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/wiki/.htaccess-bonus-tricks, without success.

I also read about the "AllowOverride All" directive for Apache but as it is cPanel I don't think I can change this - at least I can't find where to change this - though I thought/understood the "RewriteEngine On" line in .htaccess did the same thing.

I have had a look through the YOURLS issues but not found a suitable solution and a quick look here didn't reveal anything either.

I understand an intermittent issue is difficult to resolve.

FYI a couple of shortened URLS (using the domain name above): cb, peoplekey, ebay1, ozday, phpcomm, fairshare

Cheers.

Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

While poking around the YOURLS config files I found that the domain it was using in config.php is: http://aimsoftware.com.au/yourls  (excluding the www.).

Using the (now even shorter) URL seems to work more consistently.

FYI, YOURLS was set up by our web-hosting mob.
FYI2, shortened URLs above have now been removed....